# VirtualQueryEx with PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION gives error 24

Tags: c#, memory

I've been trying to follow [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/716227/Csharp-How-to-Scan-a-Process-Memory) on how to read all memory that a process has allocated. Now I'm kinda stuck on this issue:

Whenever I do a VirtualQueryEx requesting some basic memory information, the function always returns 0 and I get a Win32 error 24 (ERROR_BAD_LENGTH). As far as I know I have strictly followed the tutorial, but it seems the error lies in the tutorial source code. It seems that there is something wrong with the MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION struct, but I'm not sure.

This is a cut down version of the code:

```
const int PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 0x0400;
const int PROCESS_WM_READ = 0x0010;

public struct MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION {
  public int BaseAddress;
  public int AllocationBase;
  public int AllocationProtect;
  public int RegionSize;
  public int State;
  public int Protect;
  public int lType;
}

IntPtr processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_WM_READ, false, process.Id);

MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mem_basic_info = new MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION();

uint infoSize = (uint)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(mem_basic_info);
    VirtualQueryEx(processHandle, proc_min_address, out mem_basic_info, infoSize);
```

Could someone point me in the right direction here? Thanks in advance!

[Here's a pastebin of all the relevant code.](http://pastebin.com/BtHXGtkM)

Comment: What operating System are you using?  Try changing to FrameWork 4.0.  You are using a Win32 application so the variables sizes may be different than your project settings.

Comment: @KenWhite I included the code in the OP. Thanks!

Comment: @jdweng Okay, so changing to FrameWork 4.0 changed the error to an error 2 (ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND). I'm on Windows 10 by the way. No clue what "file" there is to be found though.

Comment: ERROR_BAD_LENGTH refers to the *infoSize* value you pass.  Get a better declaration at the pinvoke.net web site.

Comment: What value are you getting for mem_basic_info?  I count 36 bytes = 7 integers (4 bytes) plus 4 shorts (2 bytes).  Also check min_address < max_address

Answer (score 0):

64位系统的定义不一样：

```c
typedef struct _MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION32 {
    DWORD BaseAddress;
    DWORD AllocationBase;
    DWORD AllocationProtect;
    DWORD RegionSize;
    DWORD State;
    DWORD Protect;
    DWORD Type;
} MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION32, *PMEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION32;

typedef struct DECLSPEC_ALIGN(16) _MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION64 {
    ULONGLONG BaseAddress;
    ULONGLONG AllocationBase;
    DWORD     AllocationProtect;
    DWORD     __alignment1;
    ULONGLONG RegionSize;
    DWORD     State;
    DWORD     Protect;
    DWORD     Type;
    DWORD     __alignment2;
} MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION64, *PMEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION64;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).